# What is the difference between options "Network ID" and "Change" in System Properties?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, domain

What is the difference between the "Network ID" and "Change" in System Properties? I learn Active Directory and when I need to add my PC to a domain I use button "Change", click on "Domain" instead of "Workgroup", type the name of a domain and input user/password. Everything works great, but after watching some courses on YouTube, a teacher added a computer by using "Network ID" button. So the question is there any difference how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Network ID starts a wizard to guide you, Change is the manual way for the more experienced network admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, as far as I know:

- **Change** is the more manual way if you more or less know what to do.
- **Network ID** is a wizard that will help you configure it and ask you question to help you fill the relevant information.

  > If you do not know how to complete these tasks, you can use the Network Identification (ID) Wizard to help you. To start the Network ID Wizard, follow these steps

  <sup>[More information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/295017/how-to-change-a-computer-name-join-a-domain-and-add-a-computer-descrip)</sup>